# Group By a substring in a field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, substring

I have a cities table in which I have citynames like "Los Angeles (California)".

I tried to extract all the values contained between parantheses with a request, but I couldn't manage to do it well...

The request I tried looked like this :

```
SELECT cityname FROM cities WHERE cityname LIKE "%(%)%" 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(cityname, FIND_IN_SET(cityname, '('))
```

Or something like (without group by):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(cityname, FIND_IN_SET(cityname, '(')) FROM cities 
WHERE cityname LIKE "%(%)%"
```

What seems to be wrong with these requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(cityname, CHARINDEX('(',cityname)+1,
           (LEN(cityname) - CHARINDEX('(',cityname)-1)) 
FROM cities WHERE cityname LIKE '(%)%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited my first post as i forgot to precise that i was working with mySQL which doesn't recognize the CHARINDEX function :(

Comment: It's ok then ! I replaced CHARINDEX by LOCATE and LEN by LENGTH and i seemed to work fine ! Thank you !